# Getting the power spectrum from an interferogram

Tags: experimental-physics, interferometry

I'm doing analysis for a laboratory task where we used a stepper motor to vary the position of a mirror (in a Michelson interferometer) to get interferograms using different light sources. I have been trying to plot the fast fourier transform of our data to obtain the power spectrum, but with no luck.
Here is the interferogram, and its fourier transform that I have computed:
[image]

[image]
Other than the units of frequency being incorrect in the second plot (and there shouldn't be any negative frequencies, but that should be an easy fix), does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.fft import fft 
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

# Load the data
results = np.loadtxt('white_led_yellow', delimiter=' ', unpack=True, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5), skiprows=200)

# Extract the signals and positions
y1 = np.array(results[0])
y2 = np.array(results[1])
x = np.array(results[5])

# Plot the signals
plt.figure("Detector 1")
plt.plot(x, y1, 'o-')
plt.xlabel(r"Position $(\mu steps)$")
plt.ylabel("Signal 1")

plt.figure("Detector 2")
plt.plot(x, y2, 'o-')
plt.xlabel(r"Position $(\mu steps)$")
plt.ylabel("Signal 2")

# Compute the Fourier Transforms
y1_fft = fft(y1)
y2_fft = fft(y2)

# Create an array with frequencies
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y1), d=np.mean(np.diff(x)))

# Plot the Fourier Transforms
plt.figure("Fourier Transform - Detector 1")
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(y1_fft), 'x-')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.figure("Fourier Transform - Detector 2")
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(y2_fft), 'x-')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

# Find the indices of the peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(np.abs(y2_fft), height=0)

# Print the frequencies corresponding to the peaks
peak_freqs = freq[peaks]
print(peak_freqs)

plt.show()
# Plot the Fourier Transform with a limited y-axis
plt.figure("Fourier Transform - Detector 2 (Limited Y-Axis)")
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(y2_fft), 'x-')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.ylim([0, 200000000])

plt.show()
# Filter the frequencies and amplitudes to the specified range
mask = (freq >= 0.0005) & (freq <= 0.0010)
freq_filtered = freq[mask]
y2_fft_filtered = y2_fft[mask]

# Find the index of the maximum amplitude in the filtered data
peak_index = np.argmax(np.abs(y2_fft_filtered))

# Print the frequency corresponding to the peak
peak_freq = freq_filtered[peak_index]
print(peak_freq)
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Note also that without the data, the code is not all that useful.

Comment: This is a physics Q&A forum and it is unlikely that somebody will review your code for errors. I suggest that you rewrite your question and describe what you expect as to the interferogram's shape *from* physics.

Comment: Maybe my answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/60031/41790) will provide a clue.